# Change position of floating label text of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

[image: Problem]

The floating label text is appearing over the edge of EditText box. How can it be raised above the predefined level?

My Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_usernameL"
    android:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:padding="10dp"/>


</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

That my happen because of the padding, please check your xml with the following

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout   
android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText android:id="@+id/input_name" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:singleLine="true" 
android:hint="@string/hint_name" /> 
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**THis is not work well when you take drawable to edittext so do this like and give paddding to both**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/input_layout_usernameL"
android:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/yourdrawablerectagular"
android:padding="10dp"
 >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:padding="10dp"/>


  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: As you show image you are using background to your edittext right?

Comment: @TheHardRock Please add null to edittext background and setbackground to TextInputLayout and Also give padding to boths..

Answer (score 0):

This may sound bit of hacky but so does your question. :p

**Try this out.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:padding="38dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result :**

[image]

I know this is not right way to do that but still.

Hope it will help you.